# Sending email with one or more recipient in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have a field in a table that contains some email of my users. The field looked like this :

```
| no_request |    addresed_to                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   001      |    email1@domain.com, email2@domain.com, email3@domain.com  |
```

I use MVC concept using codeigniter php. So I create model like this :

```
public function sendEmail($no_request){
    $this->db->select('approved_to');
    $this->db->where('no_request', $no_request);
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_requestfix');

    return $query->row();
}
```

and this is my controller :

```
public function sendRequestKeAtasan($name, $email_user, $addressed_to, $complaint) {
    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'smtp.XXX.XXX,
        'smtp_port' => 25,
        'smtp_user' => $email_, 
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

    $message = date("h:i:s");
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from($email_user, $name);
    $this->email->to($addressed_to);
    $this->email->subject("$no_request);
    $this->email->message("$keluhan");

    if ($this->email->send()) {
        echo 'Email sent.';
    } else {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
}
```

As you can see, in addresed to in my table, I have 3 emails address. So, how can I sent the email to 3 users on ?

Comment: Please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721450/send-a-mail-to-multiple-recipients-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

As codeigniter docs provided,

> Sets the email address(s) of the recipient(s). Can be a single email,
>   a comma-delimited list or an array

For example :

```
$this->email->to('someone@example.com');
$this->email->to('one@example.com, two@example.com, three@example.com');
$this->email->to(array('one@example.com', 'two@example.com', 'three@example.com'));
```

In this case, you save email address with comma separated value. So, you can send them like this.

```
$result = $this->your_model->sendEmail($no_request);
sendRequestKeAtasan($name, $email_user, $result->addressed_to, $complaint);
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the reciptant emails to an array and pass it to `to` parameter

Check this

[Sending mail to multiple recipients with sendgrid and codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194618/sending-mail-to-multiple-recipients-with-sendgrid-and-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

just explode your $addressed_to with "," to create array and pass that to "to" method of CI email class.. Here is an example;

```
$this->email->to(explode(","$addressed_to));
```