# How to send array of emails to sendgrid in single api call?

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

I have 500 different emails to be sent to different recipients. Right now, for sending 500 mails, 500 **sendgrid** API calls are being called  and it takes approx 9-10 minutes to send to all recipients. I want to know if there is a alternative available for sending 500 mails in single sendgrid API call ? Basically I want single API call for all 500 mails.

Comment: This might help. Have a look.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194618/sending-mail-to-multiple-recipients-with-sendgrid-and-codeigniter?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [SMTP API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/using_the_smtp_api.html) for this. We have a PHP library for the SMTPAPI at [GitHub](https://github.com/sendgrid/smtpapi-php).